# How can detect a path is closed?

Tags: ios, touch-event

On iOS, there are points from touch events. When touches ended events occur I need to know a path which consist of touch points data is closed. Which algorithm is best for this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu4QG.png

I couldn't post a image because my reputation, please click above link.

Comment: define what you meant by a closed path?  two coordinates are the same?

Comment: An image I attached would be helpful.